# Struts 1 - How to define List bean with empty value

Tags: jsp, struts

I have Struts 1 / JSP web application.
In the JSP I need to define List bean and pass value to it.

```
<bean:define id="beanName" type="java.util.List" value=""/>
```

does not work. It says I should pass in NNULL value.

```
<bean:define id="beanName" type="java.util.List" value="<%= new ArrayList() =>"/>
```

does not work either - it says it could accept only String type parameters.

Could someone point me out - how could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually none of this.
I have found I could use

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanName" type="java.util.ArrayList" beanName="java.util.ArrayList" scope="page" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
<bean:define id="beanName" class="java.util.List" value=""/>
```

or

```
<bean:define id="beanName" class="java.util.List" />
```

Comment: bean define does not allow to instantiate new beans. I have found I could use <jsp:useBean ../> for this.